# Are those dia2sql tools sheet-specific?

Tags: code-generation, dia

I am using DIA v0.97.1 to draw diagrams for my database modelings. One thing that I really hope to get some advice from experienced members is about those dia2sql tools. They basically automatically parse the .dia document (xml document in essence) that you saved and generate sql statements for you. However, according to most of their documentations they seem only work with UML sheet. If I include some ER boxes, will it undermine the whole thing and render it unreadable to those dia2sql tools.? If this is, unfortunately, the case, then is there a way around that? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am happy with tedia2sql, an excellent perl dia parser.

[http://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::Dia::SQL](http://metacpan.org/pod/Parse%3a%3aDia%3a%3aSQL)